Why it is not a useful Q&A forum?
It's been a while since I'm not making daily visits.
Here, I want to "complain" about another place: the "math" stackexchange.
As DSP engineers (or more correctly electrical & electronics engineers), it's very natural that we make visits to math.stackexchange.
Unfortunately, in none of my visits I could get a useful response?
I consider this a very annoying result?
I wonder if you also have the same experience?
Or what's wrong possibly?
sincerely,
